# Old Unity exe : is there any command line argument that skips the configuration window?

Tags: unity, configuration

Remember this configuration window from older versions of Unity?
[image]

Is there some way I can run the exe that skips this and goes straight to the game?

ps. my use case is that I am writing a Windows program that loads various games for arcade-style cabinets.

Comment: My searches have not turned up any options for you. [There's a documented option to *show* this dialog](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html?_ga=2.89001116.642669515.1639538621-2121096744.1463615920) (`-show-screen-selector`), but no documented option to hide it when using an executable without access to the project source files, and no hits I'm finding from players asking for workarounds. It might be worth checking whether `-hide-screen-selector` or `-skip-screen-selector` or `-no-screen-selector` etc might work as undocumented options, but I'm doubtful.

Comment: The editor has some silent launch command line options - they might have recycled the syntax for a similar (possibly undocumented) option for the player.

Comment: You might also try using the command line options to specify all the info that the configuration window is asking for. Maybe if the information has already been provided/verified, it may skip the pop up window.